# attach event handler to bootsrap ok button, where to find html?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

Can someone tell me how to attach an event handler to a bootsrap OK button. Say for example I want to show an

```
alert("hello world");
```

when the user click on ok in the **notification dialog**.

I know how to do that with jQuery but I couldn't find the button's html so that I can add an id or class to it.

[Live Demo](http://codepen.io/m-e-conroy/pen/ALsdF)

Comment: Well, here it is your HTML: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="yes()">Yes</button>`

Comment: I mean after clicking on "Notify Dialog" and the dialog appears. how can I execute something when the user click OK in the dialog message that appeared ? @MaximMazurok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the other examples you have using `dialog.result.then`

```
// Notify Dialog
case 'notify':
    dlg = $dialogs.notify('Something Happened!','Something happened that I need to tell you.');
    dlg.result.then(function(btn){
        alert("Hey there");
    });
    break;
```